# Google search results not pulling links to documentation

Tags: general

I have experienced this from the past few days. Searching for apex related things is not showing results from documentation which was not usually the case. Usually almost all the searches related to apex classes, methods etc used to show the documentation links in the first two or three results. Some of the things I tried are System class methods apex, string class methods apex etc. I tried using duckduckgo which is doing a better job in some cases. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I've been experiencing the similar behavior from Google Search in the past 2 weeks or something.

Answer (score 2):

In a private channel, a Salesforce person mentioned the problem was with meta tags in the Apex Reference Guide pages.  They've resolved it and have re-submitted to Google for indexing.